# How to check in Java App Engine if we are on development workstation

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I'd like to do this in Java Google App Engine

```
if(developmentMode)
  foo();
else
  bar();
```

Does anyone know a good way to do this?

Daniel

Answer (score 44, accepted):

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/utils/SystemProperty

In Java just test

```
SystemProperty.environment.value() == SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Production
```

Comment: Minor note: The question asks how to check if we're on a *development* system but the test above checks if we're on a *production* system (i.e. the condition is negated).  Change to `!=` or use `SystemProperty.Environment.Value.Development`.

Answer (score 5):

In Python, check the `SERVER_SOFTWARE` environment variable.  It'll be `"Development/X.Y"` in development mode.  In Java, `ServletContext.getServerInfo()`.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/740a2f70f77c9621#) on the GAE/J Group.

Several techniques are listed there.  You might also look at [this blog entry](http://marceloverdijk.blogspot.com/2009/10/determining-runtime-environment-on.html)

It suggests doing:  `ServletContext.getServerInfo()`

"In development this will be 'Google App Engine Development/x.x.x' and in production it will be 'Google App Engine/x.x.x'"

This blog suggests writing a ServletContextListener to sniff this value so you can expose it to classes that don't have access to the ServletContext.