# Environment Specific Variables In Google App Engine Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine

What is the best way to store environment specific variables for Java Google App Engine. Right now I am storing the different values for urls or index names in a properties files. I just keep getting nervous that I will forget to change the values used for my local machine to the production next time I deploy.

Is there something we can set in app engine for our app to pull from when it's running on app engine and a file for local for example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the environment variables you have in mind are only needed **after your application gets control** you could programatically make the properties file loading decision using a method like this: [How to check in Java App Engine if we are on development workstation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1574637/how-to-check-in-java-app-engine-if-we-are-on-development-workstation)

For app config variables (outside of the app's control) or for staging/production scenarios I'm using different branches in my version control system. The strategy is described in these answers:

- [Handling cron jobs on staging environment on google app engine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33759285/handling-cron-jobs-on-staging-environment-on-google-app-engine/33760403#33760403)
- [How to handle sensitive configuration information when deploying app-engine applications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31336414/how-to-handle-sensitive-configuration-information-when-deploying-app-engine-appl/31347185#31347185)

Comment: Oh cool! Thank you for that. That will come in handy for my current situation. Though if I were to set up a staging and production app engine instance this wouldn't work. Any ideas that would cover both scenarios?

Comment: I will look into your added edit. Very cool! Thank you! I marked as answer but don't have enough reputation for it to do anything :( Thanks again!

Comment: No worries. You can always come back to it later on, when you have enough rep :)